# D3 - Event binding inside another event

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is some code to create bar graphs from Scott Murray's book "Interactive Data Visualization for the Web". The code allows the bar graphs to be generated, updated (add/remove) and sorted. It works perfectly except that I am not able to get the sort button to work. I know the sort function works because I have appended a click event (that runs the sort function) to each bar. So when a bar is clicked, the bars get sorted.

Here is the JSfiddle  - http://jsfiddle.net/kiniadit/k812fo53/3/

Here is the code segment (lines 74-77) that isn't working

```
else if(btnClass == "sort"){
    sortBars();
    sortLabels();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way in which you're setting up the handler functions for the click events. You're selecting all the buttons and attaching a single handler that determines internally what to do. This handler runs code to update the bars for *all* buttons, regardless of what happened before.

In your particular case, this means that the sorting is done correctly and the corresponding transitions set up, but then immediately cancelled by the code that's updating the bars (to handle added/removed values). This doesn't do anything in this case, so the only effect is to cancel everything that the sort handler set up.

To fix, simply exit the function after the call to the sorting functions:

```
return;
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k812fo53/4/).

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. So as best practice do you recommend creating separate event handlers for each button class?

Comment: Yes, I would create separate handler functions for each button.